# C# LinqToSQL how Select new just first table from 2 tables from CSV file

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have problem - one CSV file with 2 tables in it.
I need using something like this:

```
=======
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + fi);
string[] seps = { "\",", ",\"" };

var MyData= from line in lines.Skip(5)                                               
let data = line.Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.None)
select new My_Table_in_DB
{
Column1 = data[0],
Column2 = data[1],
...
}
======
```

select just first table.
I know that next table is beginning from this row for example - like the name of the table in next CSV-row, after first table:
"Next table"

CSV-structure something like:

```
=====
Table1
.....
...
...
Next table
....
...
...
=====
```

Help me please - how can i do such select ?

Comment: CSVs are just text.  They do not have tables.  If you have one with data concatenated, you'll have to go thru it to find the break.  Better tell whoever is putting 2 data sets into one text file to stop that.

Comment: How do you know when one table ends and the next begins?  You seem to already be considering the option of skipping and taking n lines.  Perhaps by the length of the number of columns (relating to number of separators) you can make the distinction?

Comment: But how I can find out number of columns ?
And yes - there are 2 sets of data in one CSV with different number of columns (
I need to find somehow number of row with  "Next Table" name and Skip rows after this one.
But how?

Comment: You appear to already be splitting the line...  you could perhaps have a where clause on the array length.  However, I'd preference a solution where I simplified the individual steps.  I'd like to first split up the file into the two separate files that they better belong to, and then just handle each file (or set of data), separately.

Comment: If the files contain column names as a row, that might be something to find that breaks up the file into two parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you start reading the lines just cut the lines after "next table". Something like this:

```
var table1Lines = new List<string>();
foreach(var line in lines){
    if(line == "next table"){
        break;
    }
    tablel1Lines.Add(line);
}
```

Than work on table1Lines...